# C++: strcmp being ignored

Tags: c++, image, audio, strcmp

I'm trying to make some code to detect a certain image and play a sound. In my source, I'm using ImageGetName to get the name of the image itself.

ImageGetName is as follows:

```
const char *ImageGetName(const image_c *image)
{
    const image_c *rim;

    rim = (const image_c *) image;

    return rim->name;
}
```

In my main function, I have this defined:

```
const char *image = ImageGetName(mo->subsector->sector->floor.image);
```

It should just point *image to floor.image when called and sort through them as appropriate.

Now, what I want to do is access the current image name with

```
ImageGetName(mo->subsector->sector->floor.image).
```

So to do this, I assume I have to use strcmp. But maybe I'm not doing this correctly. The block in question:

```
            if (mo->player && gravity > 0 && -zmove > OOF_SPEED && ! fly_or_swim)
        {

            if(!strcmp(image, "WATER")) //false, do no lookup
            {
            CON_Message("Normal Floor!");
            mo->player->deltaviewheight = zmove / 8.0f;
            S_StartFX(mo->info->oof_sound, P_MobjGetSfxCategory(mo), mo);
            }
            else if(strcmp(image, "WATER") == 0) //true, look this up!!
            CON_Message("Detected WATER FLAT!");
            mo->player->deltaviewheight = zmove / 10.0f;

            S_StartFX(mo->info->secretsound, P_MobjGetSfxCategory(mo), mo);
        }
```

So the problem here is that it's completely ignoring the first strcmp **if(!strcmp(image, "WATER"))** and going right to the second: **else if(strcmp(image, "WATER") == 0)**. It should not be doing that. In most cases, it should evaluate the first part as true unless the player actually steps on a WATER image.

The issue is that the player is not actually stepping on the image marked "WATER", but rather *every* single image the player steps on will produce the second output (Detected WATER!).

I need it to evaluate the image that is accessed - if it doesn't find it, "Normal Floor", and if it does, "Detected WATER!".

Using !strcmp should assume it doesn't need to even bother with looking at the image, while the normal strcmp should evaluate the image being stepped on. But this isn't happening.

Can I please have some assistance here? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Use `std::string` and enjoy comparison operators that are actually somewhat human-readable.

Comment: The implementation of `ImageGetName` is far to verbose. Just write `return image->name;`.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your indentation and *one of* your problems becomes clear:

```
if(!strcmp(image, "WATER")) //false, do no lookup
{
    CON_Message("Normal Floor!");
    mo->player->deltaviewheight = zmove / 8.0f;
    S_StartFX(mo->info->oof_sound, P_MobjGetSfxCategory(mo), mo);
}
else if(strcmp(image, "WATER") == 0) //true, look this up!!
    CON_Message("Detected WATER FLAT!");
mo->player->deltaviewheight = zmove / 10.0f;

S_StartFX(mo->info->secretsound, P_MobjGetSfxCategory(mo), mo);
```

The last two lines are not part of the `else if` block. You need to surround the statements that you want to be in the `else if` block with curly braces.

The other problem is that `!strcmp(image, "WATER")` and `strcmp(image, "WATER") == 0` do exactly the same thing - either both of them are true, or both of them are false. I don't know what you were trying to do there, but it's not what it actually does.

Answer (score 1):

1-You're missing a pair of braces to surround the `else if` block

2-`else if` will never execute regardless. strcmp **returns 0 if there is a match**, which is equivalent to false. So supposing there is a match, the condition inside `if()` will evaluate to `!0` which evaluate to true. The `else if (condition)` evaluates to `else if (0==0) which is also equal to true. Remove the`!` in the if condition and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose both if and else if conditions are same. I do not really understand what you are going to do there as one of answer reflects. Can you provide more input on that?

It is like that when if fails all else if are being looked up and if they also fail it will go to else condition. Correct me if wrong. For you both condition are same.

if (!0) == true and if (0 == 0) == true

and here both condition for the player is also same as described by detection of water.

In games I feel better use strcmpi() instead of strcmp().However, that won't give you solution here where both conditions are same.